# Why do I get an AJAX error during installation?

Tags: installation

I tried to install Drupal 7.10. When the installation has installed 28/29 modules, I get the following error.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
> HTTP Result Code: 200
> Debugging information follows.
> Path: http://localhost/drupal/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en&id=1&op=do
> StatusText: OK
> ResponseText: ( ! )
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\drupal\includes\database\mysql\database.inc on line 153

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the  maximum execution time being exceeded. To fix this, you should change the maximum execution time in your php.ini file. Click on the Wamp icon on the taskbar, select PHP -> php.ini, find "max_execution_time" and change it from 30 to like 100-300, to make sure even the slower scripts get their job done before the timeout.

Remember to restart the server after you change the settings.

Comment: i checked and change it to 200, but it still displayed: Maximum execution time of **30** seconds exceeded

Comment: Did you restart all services?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting a similar error during Drupal installation, with *Drupal already installed* as response text. I fixed the error by changing the following values in the php.ini file used for the site.

```
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 180
max_input_nesting_level = 300
memory_limit = 512M
```